# basic haskell: Comparing a set of Ints and a set of set of ints

Tags: haskell

is there an easy way in which I can check if two lists contain common elements.

Ie

```
set1 = [1,2,3,4]
set2 = [[1,5,7],[1,2,3,8]]
```

Would there be a way I could potentially isolate elements that were in set1 but not in any of the sets in set2?
Would the best way be to add the x-amount of sets in set2 together to have one big set (using concat) to compare to set1 or is this a waste of time?

Much appreciated for any advice.

Comment: Why not try a few of your ideas and see what works and what you learn? Then browse the `Data.Set` library, and read about how sets can be implemented efficiently, and about algorithms for the basic set operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.Set as Set
foldl (\x y -> Set.difference  x (Set.fromList y)) (Set.fromList set1) set2
```

Gives the following output:

```
fromList [4]
```

And will always give the members of set1 which are not in any of the sets within set2 - which seems to be your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
filter (`notElem` (concat set2)) set1
```

It will return list of all elements from `set1` that are not in any of the list from `set2`. However, I have no idea about its spatial complexity.

Comment: didn't work
"expected type Int -> Bool"
Actual type: [[int]] -> Bool

Comment: @John Sorry, backquotes were missing around `notElem`. Now it works.

Comment: @John It should be `filter (\`notElem\` concat set2) set1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of all the elements in `set2` and use that to filter `set1`:

```
import Data.Set as Set
let s = foldl (flip Set.insert) Set.empty (join set2) in [e | e <- set1, e `notMember` s]
```